# Normalizer of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ in $SU(4)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-computer

What is the [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ in $SU(4)$ or how would I find it?

Reason for the question: with 2 qubits, if I was interested in conjugation of 2-qubit gates with generic $SU(2)$ elements, instead of with elements of the Pauli group, what 2-qubit gates would be preserved by such operation (similarly to Clifford gates for the case of Pauli group)?